# Avoiding trub in bottles post primary fermentation

Tags: clarity, trub

I've got a batch that's been in primary for about a week & I've hit my desired FG.  While taking the gravity measurement, there's a lot of trub from hop pellets floating around (despite using a tap well above the base of the bucket).

I've done a bit of research and found a few techniques for reducing the transfer of trub to bottles.

1. Cold clarification
2. Secondary fermentation
3. Racking on to something like gelatine

I've currently got no secondary / racking equipment but do have a temperature controlled setup.  If it's worth the investment, I'm willing to buy some kit.

What's the most effective approach for keeping the gunk out of my bottled beer & why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let it sit for another week in a cooler place than your original primary.  A fridge is nice, but not everyone has that kind of space.
Even with the cold conditioning to help clarification, you do need a racking cane set up.
I've never had much luck using the post at the base of a bucket from a primary ferment.  My trub is always up to the level of the port inside. I'd rack from the top down and not attempt to drain from the port on the side of the bucket.

Use your racking cane and hold it 6 inches off the bottom as you rack to a bottling bucket.
Then as you can see the beer get closer to the trub slowly lower the racking cane with the level of the beer.

If you only have the one bucket there isn't much you can do now.  Just go slow and hope for the best.  You need to have a seperate bottling bucket set up from the primary if you want less "stuff" in the bottles.

Comment: Agreed. You for sure need a racking set up: a racking cane or auto siphon and ~5ft of 3/8 tubing. This should cost about $15. I can't recommend the [auto siphon](http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/auto-siphon-1-2.html)  highly enough, it changed my life. A cheap secondary is another bucket OR a carboy.