# Cider clarification with minimal equipment

Tags: cider, clarity

[Related](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/avoiding-trub-in-bottles-post-primary-fermentation)

I've got a batch of cider that has just finished primary fermentation. My last batch come out with a lot of sediment and yeasty flavors which I'm trying to avoid with this batch.

Like the OP in the related question, I don't currently have any secondary / racking equipment and I'm trying to avoid purchasing too much more equipment right now.

The accepted answer to the question recommends against bottling from the tap on the side of the fermenter because

> My trub is always up to the level of the port inside.

and I'm wondering if this is any different for cider because the sediment that has settled so far is not up to the level of the port.

I've been sold some Colloidal Silicon Dioxide as a fining agent and I'd like to know if this alone will allow me to bottle directly from the tap.

I'm also wondering if it would be a good idea to leave the cider in the fermenter for a while after adding the Silicon Dioxide. My fermenter is only half full with the current batch and I've read that disturbing the Carbon Dioxide layer when there's a lot of headspace can be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of things. Racking is normally part of the process to get the cider off the yeast so it doesn't taste too yeasty. If you can't find carboy to rack it into, you should bottle it immediately. The second problem you are going to run into is oxidation. Extended storage in a glass carboy with very little headroom is what you want. Like and inch or two from the airlock. if you don't add some metabisulfites for aging even for a couple of weeks, you will have a bad oxidation problem. I've never heard of Colloidal Silicon Dioxide being used as a fining agent. Pectic Enzyme is typically used during fermentation to break down the pectic haze.

Comment: Yeah I've read about Pectic Enzyme, it's unfortunately too late for this batch as fermentation is already complete. The Silicon Dioxide was what my local brewing store sold as a fining agent and it recommends being stirred in and then being left for at least two days. Is that too long given the oxidation risk?

Comment: No that would be fine. Two days isn't going to make much of a difference, but you should bottle it as soon as it falls clear.